# click to activate the hidden `td` and another click to deactivate the hidden` td`

Tags: angular, typescript

I just want to know a small thing. I will wish to improve the button for the showing of a hidden `td`.

When I click on the button `1` for example, the elements hidden are displayed.

[image]

My problem is that I want a click to activate the hidden `td` and another click to deactivate the hidden`td` for display each elements of the table.

[image]

The code is on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f7ks6n?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: So, your problem is that clicking the button the second time don't hide the "hidden elements"?

Comment: @Simo: Yes, exactly, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr *ngIf="currentIndex === i && show">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td colspan="6">
        <ng-container>
          <table
            class="table table-striped"
            style="width:100%; text-align: center;"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr style="color: red">
                <th scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Note 1</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Note 2</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td scope="col" style="">5</td>
                <td scope="col" style="">8</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>

 toggle(index) {
    console.log(index);
    this.currentIndex = index;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if (this.show) {
      this.buttonName = 'Hide';
      this.show = false;
    } else {
      this.buttonName = 'Show';
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
```

You were not actually toggling the div

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cah9af?file=src/app/app.component.ts . Please check this link for any errors

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that i've understand correctly your request, in your `toggle()` function replace

```
this.currentIndex = index;
```

with

```
 if(index === this.currentIndex) {
      this.currentIndex = null;
    } else {
      this.currentIndex = index;
    }
```

You have to reset the current index once the function is recalled on the currently selected td button.